# how to send asci and non asci character over serial port from bash (script)

Tags: linux, bash, serial-port, hex, non-ascii-characters

I try to send some hex values (mixed with asci chars).

what i like to have:
send_string = {0x2d, 0x2e, 0x01,..., "Hallo"}

what i am able to get:
send_string= "0x2d0x2e0x10...Hallo"

## Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#USB device path
USBDEV=/dev/ttyUSB0


#disable DTR
stty -F $USBDEV -hupcl
#set baud
stty -F $USBDEV 9600

pattern1=0x2d
pattern2=0x2e
adr=0x01
cmd=0x21

nl=0x0a
end=0x00

txt1="Hallo"
txt2="Bye"

string=$(echo ${pattern1}${pattern2}${adr}${cmd}"test"${nl}"haha"${end})
#string=$(echo \0x2e\0x2d\0x01\0x21"test"\0x0a"haha"\0x00)

echo $string
echo $string >> $USBDEV

exit 0
```

## Output

`0x2d0x2e0x010x21test0x0ahaha0x00`

## Problem

The hex values of vars `pattern1`, `pattern2`, `adr`, ... should be stored in the string as not ASCI charackters.

If the string would be prepered as i need to, the output must have non asci characters. But it has not.

i tried some ways but all gained confusion only.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `$''` special quotes.

```
pattern1=$'\x2d'
```

This doesn't work for `\x00`, though. The only possible way to print it I know is

```
printf '\x00'
```

but you can't assign it to a variable. You need to switch to a more advanced scripting language to be able to do it. For example, in Perl

```
$end = "\x00";
```

works fine.

Comment: thx for your hint! this bring me a bit forward. 0x00 seems to be not the only one that not works. $'\x0a'  (\n) does not print out and been not recognized from the device on ttyUSB0. Furthermore, it seems that the `pattern1`,`pattern2`, `adr` and `cmd`  been recognized  correctly by the device on  USB0 but the Outpu is: `-.!test haha` i will update my question with your hints and the new Output

Comment: You need to double quote the variables to keep them intact. Using `printf` instead of `echo` is safer, too.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `printf` directly for binary data; you can't store arbitrary binary data (namely, a null byte) in a shell variable.

```
#!/bin/bash

#USB device path
USBDEV=/dev/ttyUSB0


#disable DTR
stty -F $USBDEV -hupcl
#set baud
stty -F $USBDEV 9600

printf '.-\001!%s\n%s\000' "$txt1" "$txt2" > "$USBDEV"

exit 0
```